# Spring JPA returning only fields, not entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a Query-annotated Spring JPA repo which looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MainRepository 
extends 
    JpaRepository<MainEntity, MainEntity.ID>, 
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<MainEntity> {

    @Query("select e.start, e.finish,e.forename,e.surname from MainEntity e where e.volunteerId= :id "
        + "and e.areaId>0 and e.isAssignment=true order by e.start")
    List<MainEntity> findAssignments(@Param("id") int volunteerId);
}
```

This is not returning a list of MainEntity objects, however, despite the return type. It is returning a List of Object[] corresponding to the requested field types.

What's going on???

Comment: Have you tried `select e from MainEntity e`?

Comment: I was wondering about that, I tried `select *...` and `select e.*` but both failed.

Comment: `SELECT e FROM MainEntity e` will return the full entity. If you want a set of fields, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43331990/1426227).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, JPA will return a list of `Object[]` when the query returns a list with a *projection*, that is, a set of fields from an entity (or multiple entities).

With Spring Data JPA you can avoid the `Object[]` and return the data in a *more elegant format* by defining an interface like the following:

```java
public interface MainEntityProjection {
    String getStart();
    String getFinish();
    String getForename();
    String getSurname();
}
```

And changing your query method to return the above defined interface:

```java
@Query("SELECT e.start, e.finish, e.forename, e.surname " +
       "FROM MainEntity e " +
       "WHERE e.volunteerId = :id AND e.areaId > 0 AND e.isAssignment = true " +
       "ORDER BY e.start")
List<MainEntityProjection> findAssignments(@Param("id") int volunteerId);
```

This approach is described in the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

---

Apart from Spring Data JPA, JPA itself handles it with `SELECT NEW`, using a public constructor. You would define a class as following:

```java
public class MainEntityProjection {

    private String start;
    private String finish;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;

    public MainEntityProjection(String start, String finish,
                                String forename, String surname) {
        this.start = start;   
        this.finish = finish;
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And then your query would be like:

```sql
SELECT NEW org.example.MainEntityProjection(e.start, e.finish, e.forename, e.surname)
FROM MainEntity e
WHERE e.volunteerId = :id AND e.areaId > 0 AND e.isAssignment = true
ORDER BY e.start
```

The above query is also expected to work with Spring Data JPA (your method will return a list of `MainEntityProjection` then).

Check what the [JSR 338](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf), the document that defines JPA 2.1, says about using `SELECT NEW` and constructor expressions:

> **4.8.2 Constructor Expressions in the SELECT Clause**
>
> A constructor may be used in the `SELECT` list to return an instance of a Java class. The specified class is not required to be an entity or to be mapped to the database. The constructor name must be fully qualified.
>
> If an entity class name is specified as the constructor name in the `SELECT NEW` clause, the resulting entity instances will be in either the new or the detached state, depending on whether a primary key is retrieved for the constructed object.
>
> If a *single_valued_path_expression* or *identification_variable* that is an argument to the constructor references an entity, the resulting entity instance referenced by that *single_valued_path_expression* or *identification_variable* will be in the managed state.
>
> For example,
>
> ```sql
> SELECT NEW com.acme.example.CustomerDetails(c.id, c.status, o.count)
> FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o
> WHERE o.count > 100
> ```

Answer (score 0):

write like this:

```
 @Query("from MainEntity e where e.volunteerId= :id "
        + "and e.areaId>0 and e.isAssignment=true order by e.start")
```

Comment: oops you seem to have missed "SELECT e" off that JPQL

Comment: it can also be used without "select e"

Comment: Errm, no it cant if you are compliant with the JPA spec.

Answer (score 0):

You don't request entity but fields of it. Whereas the object array returned.
Try that :.

```
      Select e from MainEntity e ...
```